# create a foreach table in html email template php

Tags: php, html, css, email

I have an email template am trying to send to users after they have ordered for some items. to send the email am using inline css with html as the email teplate where it is saved as .html. the problem is how do i load all the items the user bought into a for each table and pass it to the email html template file before sending it

```
<tbody style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;">
    {{ item }}
</tbody>
```

this is my php for sending the mail

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = "email@email.com";
$mail->FromName = "test";
$mail->addAddress($email); //Recipient name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo("email@email.com", "Reply");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$variables = array();
$variables['name'] = 'john';
$template = file_get_contents("eorder.html");
foreach($data as $row){
$eprodname = $this->get_name_from_id('product_name','product','product_id',$row['id']);
$variables['item'] ='<tr style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;page-break-inside: avoid;">
<td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">1</td>
<td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $eprodname .'</td>
 <td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $row['quantity'] .'</td>
 <td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $row['price'] .'</td>
</tr>';

}
foreach($variables as $key => $value)
{
  $template = str_replace('{{ '.$key.' }}', $value, $template);
}
$mail->Subject = "Order Details";
$mail->Body = $template;
$mail->Send();
```

**My problem:** I have with this code is that if a user orders more than one product, this code will only load the last product on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding your `$variables['item']` key. You need to change this to array

```
foreach($data as $row){
$eprodname = $this->get_name_from_id('product_name','product','product_id',$row['id']);
$variables['item'][] ='<tr style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;page-break-inside: avoid;">
<td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">1</td>
<td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $eprodname .'</td>
 <td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $row['quantity'] .'</td>
 <td style="-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;padding: 8px;line-height: 1.428571429;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;background-color: #fff!important;">'. $row['price'] .'</td>
</tr>';

}
```

Comment: it outputs Array as the value not the array items buy Array

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing `{{ item }}` with `$value`! That it is one "key" and you want replace it by your array!!
You should combine your items and then replace with 'item' one time!

Comment: You have 1 `{{ item }}` in your template! When you are iterating on your array and replacing with `{{ '.$key.' }}`, it works only for first item! and other items cant replace with anything!!